# How to read the value from web config in AngularJs Controller

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, web-config

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
            <add key="var1" value="SomeValue"/>
      </appSettings>
<configuration>
```

I want to read this var1 in angularJS controller
Like this...

```
function ReadConfigurationSettings()
    {
        var k = '<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["var1"].ToString() %>'
        alert(k);
    }
```

but its not working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get a value from web config directly. One option is to put the value into a meta tag in your index html for example like this:

```
<meta name="var1" content="@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["var1"]" />
```

Then you can get that value from angular like this:

```
var var1 = angular.element(document).find('meta[name=var1]').prop("content");
```